# htaccess /index.php extensions shows after redirected from old domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a redirect issue occurring, So far, I've redirected all non-www to www, and an old domain to the new domain. I've also remove the `/index.php` extension which works unless redirecting from the old domain. Ideally I'd like this to not occur. This is really a shot in the dark for me, as I don't understand what much of this means (htaccess code), but I got it working for the most part so far.

**What I am trying to do:**
Ultimately I'm attempting to remove all `.php` extensions (*Some of the pages on the old domain use `.html` as an extension, they are now `.php` pages. so there's a redirect for those as well in there*) and have everything routed to the new www.domain.com (not domain.com).

Is there a specific order to execute the redirects in? Or am I just missing something entirely. `.htaccess` isn't my strong suite. Additionally, should I have these in separate `<IfModules>`? (they currently are, I combined them into one for less code in this post)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # redirect to new domain
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # html > php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R]

    #not sure what this does, but was already here, so I'm leaving it... site does not use ssl.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]


    # force www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


    # remove /index.php
    RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give the following a try. I've shuffled things around and simplified them for you. Descriptions in the comments.

```sh
DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

    # Fire up the engines
    RewriteEngine On

    # The base is not necessarily needed. Enable it if you think it might be needed.
    #
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect to new domain (self-explanatory)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Force www. on newdomain.com (plain method)
    # If you want to prevent this when using localhost/127.0.0.1/::1,
    # then uncomment the next two lines just above the rule.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.com [NC]
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=localhost
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Remove "index.php"
    RewriteRule ^index.php(/.*)?$ $1 [R=302,L]

    # Redirect *.html to *.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [R=302,L]

    # If the request does not match a file/directory,
    # internally map it as a QUERY_STRING to index.php.
    # As we're using a query string, might be best to allow
    # new query strings as well.
    #
    # If you would rather use REQUEST_URI, then use the commented
    # rule at the bottom and make sure to comment out the first one.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Regarding the 302 redirects - make them 301s if you're happy and wish for them to be permanent.

Comment: Wow, you really trimmed that down. I'll have to read up on [QSA] to figured out what exactly that does, but I really appreciate this!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Essentially, you were passing the request to index.php as a query string with out the QSA flag. As such, if you wanted to add a parameter, you'd have to use `/hello&page=3`, for example. Using QSA allows you to change it  to `/hello?page=3`.